# Post with Jax-RS

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, post, jax-rs

This really should be a simple question, and I apologize but I just can't seem to find the answer. From my understanding you can take in an object and have it use say a bean in Java EE to produce this Object/Entity into a database. Now the problem is the ID is going to be auto-generated so the client will not know this when first being created. How do I return with the @POST in Jax-RS what there now provided URI/ID location is so they know who they are provided that ID after being created. I have read and thought this was possible but maybe I am wrong, if someone could point me in the direction of my solution.

Comment: When POSTing (creating) a resource, if the operation was successful, the service should return the id of the newly created resource. It might be in json, xml, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really doesn't have much to do with REST, this is a JPA question.  The `EntityManager`'s [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) and [persist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29) will return a managed entity.  It will have the id/key in it.  Just return that in the `@POST`.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses, to be honest I hadn't gotten that far into testing but that clears this up for me so I know that I am doing things right. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you send a json object with the id filled in the response?